# Warning when not all constructors call required code

Tags: c#, vb.net, constructor

Is there some pattern that will cause compile time warning indicating that not all constructors call some required initialization code.

For example, a class similar to or even generated by Windows Designer, has InitializeComponent method, which is required to run properly.
That class can contain constructor that won't call the generated constructor which calls the InitializeComponent and also won't call the InitializeComponent method directly.

That's fine for the compiler. But is there some pattern that will generate a warning in such situation? I'm curious, because if I have a class with lots of constructors that are chained one to another, it's not that obvious when calling one will call required additional initialization code and forcing an explicit call the required initialization method in every constructor is not that elegant, I think.

Comment: Nope.  This is what unit tests are for.

Comment: Ideally, make all your constructors chain to one "canonical" constructor, and make that the only place you need initialization code... but yes, you'll need tests to make sure you've actually done that.

Comment: IMHO, initialization methods like InitializeComponent are an anti-pattern ... (except they are private and called by the base class of course).